# Filtered table in React.js

Tags: react.js, jsx

I am doing a filtered table in react, and I came up with the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import RowFilter from './RowFilter';
import List from './List';
import movieList from './movielist.json';

const data = movieList;
const App = () => (
  <RowFilter data={data}>
    <List/>
  </RowFilter>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The implementation details are not that important since this is only a rough example, but the general idea is the following:

`List` normally expects a `data` array property so that it knows what to render

`RowFilter` has an input element and keeps track of a list of data. When the value changes, it updates the list of data.

`RowFilter` also sets the `data` property for it's child, whatever that child is

The result code works as expected, but I'm wondering about whether this is hard to read or considered a bad practice in general.

[Running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k04wxq2l53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with what [Dan Bovey](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185968/159615) says, and I would go one step further to make it more explicit and make `RowFilter` take a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html):

```
<RowFilter
  data={data}
  render={(filteredData) => <List data={filteredData}/>}
/>
```

With this you can see exactly what is getting passed to your `List`, and you can use this `RowFilter` to wrap other components too.

Comment: I really feel I should change my accepted answer now but I don't know what's the proper Stack Etiquette on this...

Comment: I'm not really sure either.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's hard to read and only by looking at the source for RowFilter can you understand that it's injecting props into the child component that is given to it. Instead of passing it in as a child, you should pass it in a `component` prop.

```
<RowFilter data={data} component={List} />
```

Then in RowFilter.js, the render simply looks like this. Note the `component` prop gets renamed to uppercase.

```
<Component data={this.state.filteredData} />
```

[Here's an updated example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3kvmrv51w5)